# Simulink masks: detect press on "Ok", "Cancel" and "Apply"

Tags: matlab, simulink, mask

I would like to know if there's anyway to detect when the user press "Ok", "Cancel" or "Apply" on a simulink mask.
I need to detect mask closure and perform operation on it. I know for doing it that this is possible with a custom interface (you can set a callback for clicking on the "X" and or any button you place), but I cannot find it for a mask.

Is it even possible ?

Comment: Mask initialization commands should get called when you press ok or apply. It may not get called for cancel. Have you tried adding code in mask initialization?

Comment: mask initialization commands occurs on various events (a simple set_param will trigger it) and the aim of my needs is to control initialization and callbacks.

I need to differenciate OK, from CANCEL.

Actually, I had a support case with MathWorks, and they answered it is impossible